# Using phonegap to develop an Android app

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to develop a `PhoneGap` app on android platform. For that I referred [official site](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) of Phonegap and also installed `NodeJS`. After that according to that document I also executed `C:\> npm install -g phonegap` command to install PhoneGap. Then I also downloaded PhoneGap 2.9.1 from archives section. Now the problem is that according to [this doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html),it states that there will be `cordova-1.8.0.js` and `cordova-1.8.0.jar` from cordova download,but there is no such jar inside that folder. I am also not getting where I should download cordova-android plugin. I downloaded cordova from [this link](http://cordova.apache.org/#download) and extracted its content but there is no such file - `cordova-1.8.0.jar1`. What should I do? I am confused on using PhoneGap with Android. Please help me for that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Follow this url for the creation of your application in phone gap in android

> URL:
>   http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html

Cheers. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks... i will try this steps. But in this tutorial its using `PhoneGap 2.2.0` which i downloaded from Github and it contains `cordova-2.2.0.jar` but the latest `PhoneGap 2.9.1` doesn't contain any cordova jar.Its just contains `cordova.js` file. Why its like this?

Comment: Dont have idea about it but will get it and get back soon. and if find this answer useful pls accept the answer.

Comment: @Balu..it works properly on 4.2.1 but doesn't work on 4.2.2..why is it so?

Comment: @zanky: What is the error it giving can you share it. because ideally it should not do so..

Comment: No its not giving any error, but according to your link, it should show an alert of "PhoneGap is working" which is not displayed on 4.2.2 device.